# How to extend components from npm packages properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I use package `"react-simple-tree-menu": "^1.1.4"` ([link to package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-tree-menu)) to make tree menu. It works well but unfortunately it does not exactly meet my requirements.

```
import React from 'react';
import TreeMenu, {ItemComponent} from 'react-simple-tree-menu'
import './ClientsTree.css'

export const ClientsTree = _ => (
    <TreeMenu data={treeData}>
        {({search, items}) => (
            <ul className={"tree-item-group"}>
                {items.map(props => {
                    return <ItemComponent {...{
                        ...props,
                        label: props.label + ' value: ' + props.value
                    }}/>
                })}
            </ul>
        )}
    </TreeMenu>
);
```

As you can see it exposes **ItemComponent**, which corresponds to one node of tree menu. I changed it a bit enriching it with new value called `value`. But it just extends that what previously was label. At the end I want label text be formatted to the left and value to the right.

```
class MyItemComponent extends ItemComponent {
    render() {
        return super.render()
    }
}
```

I decided to inherit from **ItemComponent** and create **MyItemComponent** and then change the look. Unfortunately it does not to work, because throws error:

> TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'

And it comes my question how to extend this class properly or maybe there is another way to change this ItemComponent in such a way I need.

Comment: We did something similar with a different tree component by pulling the git repo for the project, putting it into our project structure and then modifying it to fit our needs, and then changing the import to pull from our project's internal location instead of the npm location.

Comment: @TechGnome It turned out to be the best solution, thank you!